# Geopandas & Mapplotlib, how do I plot without an outline around any shape?

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

When I run the code below in a Jupyter Notebook,
I get a map of the world, colored in red.

[image]

There are fine white-ish lines between the countries.
Is there a way to plot the world so that all countries
are solid and there's no line in between?

I'm asking, because my real world usecase is a fine grid that
behaves just like the world map: Each grid shape has a fine outline 
which I do not want to have in the plot. (Update, since this was asked: The grid shapes will not have the same fill color.

[image: grid example])

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world['total'] = 1
world.plot(column='total', cmap='Set1')
```

For the grid example, the grid files are at https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3c1f46241cbb4b669e18b002e4893711_0
A simplified example that shows the problem.

```
sf = 'Hexagone_125_km/Hexagone_125_km.shp'
shp = gpd.read_file(sf)
shp.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
shp['sum'] = 1  # for example, fill sum with something
shp.plot(figsize=(20,20), column='sum', cmap='gnuplot', alpha=1, legend=True)
```

Comment: Is your final goal to have a uniform color for all polygons (like red in your example)? Or do you actually want to use a color map for a column with varying values (and so get different colors for different polygons), but still get rid of the fine outlines?

Comment: The grid later has different colors for each grid entry, so the colors are different. I just want no outline at all.

Comment: Ah, that's more difficult. For a uniform color, you could make sure to give the "edge" the same color as the polygon fill (by default, no edge color is used), but for variable color using the `column` and `cmap` keywords, there is no easy option to specify to use the same color for both the edge and fill ("face").

Comment: Since by default, no edge color is used, if you set `linewidth=0.001`, the visual effect should be almost equivalent with no outlines.

Comment: I've added a picture, so that you can see the grid, alas linewidth=0.001 still produces a visible grid

Comment: One possibility would be to add a small buffer around each polygon in the grid, so instead of touching, they would *slightly* overlap, and so you wouldn't see those grid lines (but this is more a hack than a real solution)

Comment: Is this question about the countries edges or about some hexbin edges that are not in the code?

Comment: I put up the countries as an easy to test example of the lines, since downloading the grid would is a bit too much to ask. I'll update the description with a link to the grid files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The white lines are due to antialiasing. This usually makes the visual more smooth, but leads to white lines in between different shapes. You can turn off anialiasing via

```
antialiased=False
```

That has the inevitable drawback of the plot looking pixelated.

An alternative is to give the patches an edge with a certain linewidth. The edges should probably have the same color as the faces, so

```
edgecolor="face", linewidth=0.4
```

would be an option. This removes the white lines, but introduces a slight "searing" effect (You'll notice mainly looking at islands like Indonesia or Japan). This will be the more noticable, the smaller the features, so it may be irrelevant for showing a hexbin plot. Still, playing a bit with the linewidth might improve the result further.

[image]

Code for reproduction:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world['total'] = np.random.randint(0,10, size=len(world))

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(7,10))

world.plot(column='total', cmap='Set1', ax=ax1)

world.plot(column='total', cmap='Set1', ax=ax2, antialiased=False)

world.plot(column='total', cmap='Set1', ax=ax3, edgecolor="face", linewidth=0.4)


ax1.set_title("original")
ax2.set_title("antialiased=False")
ax3.set_title("edgecolor='face', linewidth=0.4")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("world.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks. `antialiased=False` worked great, for `edgecolor='face'`I had to set the linewidth to 1.0 to remove the grid lines.