# Deleting inner lines of polygons after dissolving in geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geopandas

I'm working with a geodataframe of a city where every unit is a district (administrative division). Its plot looks like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('districts_lima.geojson')
df.plot()
```

[image: districts]

Then, I'm merging some geographic units into larger groups, using a variable named `zone`. The result is:

```
df2 = df.dissolve(by='zone', aggfunc='sum')
df2.plot(column='population', legend=True, cmap='Blues')
```

[image: population by zones]

My only problem is that when I reproduce the same plot with darker borders, it becomes evident that some of the merged polygons (zones) have inner lines, which are inner district borders from the original geodataframe. This is shown clearly in this plot:

```
df2.plot(column='population', legend=True, cmap='Blues', edgecolor='black')
```

[image: population by zones with borders]

Is there a way to use geopandas to delete the inner lines of the polygons so they wouldn't appear in the last plot?

My data can be found [here](https://github.com/luisesanmartin/Share/blob/master/districts_lima.geojson).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774835/9978945

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found a good solution that pertains specifically to the fact that my issue is being created after applying the `dissolve()` property of `geopandas`. Apparently, the problem was generated by unnoticeable differences in the borderlines of contiguous inner units which prevented the collapsing to delete the interior lines of the resulting polygons.

This is solved by adding a small buffer to widen the polygon lines so those unnoticeable differences are removed and every inner line of the initial polygons actually overlap. Specifically, I needed to add:

`df2['geometry'] = df2['geometry'].buffer(0.0001)`

before

`df2 = df.dissolve(by='zone', aggfunc='sum')`

So now the plot command

`df2.plot(column='population', legend=True, cmap='Blues', edgecolor='Black')`

yields:

[image: the result I was looking for]

Comment: Doesn't this actually modify the original geometry polygons? Looking at the docs, https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/geometric_manipulations.html#examples-of-geometric-manipulations the polygons are changed, both enlarged and smoothed. I guess it is OK, as long as you don't have to do some other location sensitive operation after this, like spatial joins with points or similar.

Comment: @MagnusPersson that's correct, it does modify the original geometry. In my case, it was acceptable because I was only trying to generate a plot that could be easily understood by humans. But it is true that this solution won't  fit all cases

Answer (score 1):

Use axes (ax1) to enable plotting several layers on a common axes. Also use zorder, to arrange the layers, higher values put the layer above the ones with lower values.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
...
# bottom layer (has thick black lines)
df2.plot(column='population', legend=True, cmap='Blues', edgecolor='black', ax=ax1, zorder=5, lw=6)
# top layers (thin boundary lines)
df2.plot(column='population', legend=True, cmap='Blues', ax=ax1, zorder=6)
```

Hopefully the top layer will hide almost all the bottom layer, but partial external boundary lines.

Comment: It works for the plot. You can see it at the final graph of this notebook: https://github.com/luisesanmartin/data-vis-public-policy-course/blob/master/notebooks/1_grouping%20districts%20of%20lima.ipynb

Comment: Nonetheless, I'll definitely need to do some GIS analysis with the result, so I still have to find a way to delete the inner lines

Comment: @Luise Use `df3 = df2.dissolve(by='????')`. With proper value for 'by' you will get the combined area as single polygon in `df3`, that will eliminate the inner boundaries.

Comment: thanks for following up and apologies for not having replied earlier. I actually find a workaround by setting a buffer zone before dissolving the polygones. I added the line `df2['geometry'] = df2['geometry'].buffer(0.0001)` before `df2 = df.dissolve(by='zone', aggfunc='sum')` and worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm not adding it as the answer to the question though, because strictly speaking it is not the answer to the question I asked

Comment: @Luise If you found a good solution, please answer your own question and mark as accepted answer. This is what we often do. You will give readers a chance to vote up.